# Angular2 Response not casting

Tags: spring-boot, angular

I am making a call to my backend server (Spring Boot) and it returns a list of objects Foo.

However, when I go to list my objects in *ngFor it doesn't iterate at all.  I know my server is return a list of two objects, as I have debugged it, and the response back is an array of two objects.  I think I am missing a silly step, and any help is greatly appreciated.

foo.ts

```
name: string;
id: number;
description: string;
```

list-foo.service.ts

```
@Injectable
export class ListFooService
constructor(private _http: Http) {}
private _getFooUrl = '/api/foos/foos';

getFoos() {
    return this._http.get(this._getFooUrl)
        .map(res => <Foo[]> res.json())
        .do(data => console.log(data))
}
```

And this I know returns an array of two objects, as show in the last step of my chain.

```
@Component({
selector: 'foo-component',
templateUrl: 'app/templates/foo.component.html'
})


export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _listFooService:ListFooService) {
}

foos:Foo[];
errorMessage:string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getFoos();
}

getFoos() {
    this._listFooService.getFoos()
        .subscribe(
            foos => {this.foos = foos; console.log("Foos"); console.log(this.foos)},
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

and my foo.component.html

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#foo of foos">
    {{foo.name}}
</li>
</ul>
test
```

I get nothing to show, except for test (which is outside of my for block)

and if it helps here is the backend

FooController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/connectors")
public @ResponseBody List<Foo> getFooList()
{
    return fooDAO.getAllFoos(); //this works
}
```

and Foo.java

```
private String name;
private int id;
private String description;
//getters and setters
```

and the `<head>` in my html file

```
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/upgrade.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
```

And the JSON response back from the server is

```
[
 {
  "name": "Foo",
  "id": 1,
  "description": "FooBar"
 },
 {
   "name": "Foo2",
   "id": 2,
   "description": "FooBar2"
 }
]
```

Comment: Add the `ListFooService` to the Providers of the Component: `providers: [ListFooService]`

Comment: I have tried that and got the same result :(  Thanks though

Comment: Does the console log something?

Comment: yes, it logs [Object, Object] and when I expand it, it shows the the two objects and their data

Comment: Hmm, can you maybe make a plunker?

Comment: I would suggest to ensure that ngFor works, initialize foo with fake data `foos:Foo[] = [{name:'test'}, {name: 'test1'}];` and check if it is rendered. If it is not rendered - try adding `directives:[NgFor]`.

Comment: @kemsky I did exactly that,  and it worked  It iterated and gave me two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should remove angular1 reference: `<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>`, if it still does not help compare your script order and module versions with angular2-quickstart sample.

Comment: This was it!  I need angular1 because it is a hybrid application, but I removed it, and bootstrapped it as an Angular 2 app, and it worked!  I know the router had issues with a hybrid, maybe the http does too,

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data in the JavaScript code, perhaps you forgot to include the angular2-polyfills.js into your main HTML file. This contains ZoneJS that is responsible to trigger the change detection. The latter will update the view accordingly.

Here is the line:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: I double checked and it is there.  I have edited my original post to show the scripts I am using

Answer (score 0):

Change your foos declaration to

```
foos:Foo[] = [];
```

This is a guess as you have not shown an error message, but I have seen this behavior with an uninitialized collection.

If not, are there any errors reported in the console?

Comment: I still yield the same results.  Sadly, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you post a stringified copy of the server response packet?

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "Foo",
    "id": 1,
    "description": "FooBar"
  },
  {
    "name": "Foo2",
    "id": 2,
    "description": "FooBar2"
  }
]